# Teamcity not deploy app_data folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, deployment, continuous-integration, teamcity, teamcity-7.0

I have configured Teamcity to deploy my ASP.NET MVC application to my production server via web deploy.

The whole process is working as expected except that teamcity **doesnt deploy my files in app_data folder.**

If I deploy my site from Visual Studio the folder is created as expected but not by teamcity deployment.

Any suggestions how this can be updated,

Comment: I have the same problem you have: XML file in App_Data doesn't get deployed by TeamCity. Build action for the XML file is set as content and VS 2010 deploys without issues.

Comment: Also: the file is properly added to SVN.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the app_data folder is included in your project. When using teamcity along with msdeploy it will not by default deploy any files which arn't included in the project. Right click on it and see if it says "include in project" or "exclude from project".

Also make sure you SVN ADD (or whatever your SVN system uses) as this is a common mistake to commit and forget to SVN so it never gets deployed.

Lastly, the files in APP_Data, are they set as content or compiled or none. If they are set to none it won't be deployed.

Once its incuded check in the .csproj file.

Comment: app_data included in csproj file and all files under app_data have build action as content. lastly when i deploy the site via visual studio then the folder is deployed correctly but not via teamcity

Answer (score 0):

Check

```
Build Configuration Settings->Parameters->System Properties -> system.ExcludeApp_Data
```

value must be `false`